# Do machine learning models accept cells of pandas Dataframe containing tensors or arrays?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I am implementing a fraud detection approach for graph-based data, from this article: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/optimizing-fraud-detection-in-financial-services-with-graph-neural-networks-and-nvidia-gpus/. At the "Training the GNN model" and "Using GNN embeddings for downstream tasks" parts, the article suggests translating a tabular dataset into a graph, then generate a 64-width embedding for each node, before joining them to the original tabular dataset on the respective node IDs. I have generated a 64-width node embedding tensor, however, I am unsure what to do next. I have thought about condensing the tensor into one dimension and appending them based on the node IDs, but I feel like that is not what the article is suggesting. I have also thought of adding the entire tensor into the cell, but I feel like it is not going to fit with most machine learning models. What should I do in this situation? I do apologize if this does not seem like the right place to ask the question, and will remove it if that is the case.

Comment: Hey David, thank you for your response. I am not too worried about the size, what I am worried is how should I add the embeddings to the dataframe. Currently, I am using a pandas dataframe, and to join the embeddings to its respective nodes, I do wonder whether to add the entire tensor into one cell, and have it as one feature, or to divide the entire tensors into 64 parts, and add use each part as a feature? If I were to use the former, I do not know whether the conventional machine learning models are going to be suitable or not.

Comment: Oh I do have another question, if you wouldn't mind. The article does mention adding the embeddings to the respective nodes of the original preprocessed dataset, but each row of the dataset contain two types of IDs (Card_id and Merchant Name, from my understanding), should I add two embeddings for each row then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what kind of embeddings the authors of this [NVIDIA blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/optimizing-fraud-detection-in-financial-services-with-graph-neural-networks-and-nvidia-gpus/) use to enrich the dataset, let's rephrase their approach:

- They construct a graph where **card ID's** and **merchants** represent `nodes`, and **transactions** represent `edges`. I've visualized an example below to make it clear what are `nodes` and what are `edges` (it also proves why I preferred hard sciences to art school).
- Subsequently, they create `node embeddings` using a `link prediction` task, that is to say they train a model which predicts the probability that a `card ID` and a `merchant` are connected. **Note:** This is the 64-dimensional embedding that was referred by OP.
- Now, they join these generated embeddings back into the dataset. **Note:** Since the purpose of the embeddings is to encode the probability that a given `merchant` and given `card ID` are connected, you only need one embedding per transaction, since every transaction only has 1 merchant and one card.
- Last, they fit an XGBoost algorithm on the enriched dataset to predict if a transaction is fraudulent. Although they do not mention it explicitly, the 64-dimensional embedding is joined back into the dataset as `64 features` - XGBoost cannot handle a single feature containing a vector of 64 dimensions, which is why 64 features containing a single number is the only valid option.

[image]

Visualization of type of graph created. For the sake of simplicity, the visualization assumes that every person only owns one card. Since the dataset does not contain a `transaction ID` and every row in the dataset contain one transaction, you can consider the `row index` a `transaction ID`.

Comment: This was really informative and helpful, thanks! Although I have a bit more questions.
1. If I were to add embeddings to each row, shouldn't the task's output be edge embeddings instead of nodes? All I have seen from the article are node-related.
2. From what I understand, a link prediction task's final output is to predict whether two nodes are connected by an edge. In this instance, we will retrieve a probability that two nodes are connected, then transform them into a 64 width representation, which will be added back to the dataset for downstream tasks. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @HaiNguyen you're welcome! To explain why `node embeddings` are more helpful than `edge embeddings`, we need to think about their meaning: The `node embeddings` tell us (with the link prediction task), whether a transaction from one node to another is likely or unlikely (fraudulent transactions involve unusual transactions). `Edge embeddings` will only tell us which transactions are similar to each other (e.g. if Jane Doe buys at the same store twice two different products these embeddings would have similar values); therefore, edge embeddings would not help us find suspicious transactions.